# Update syntax right but zero rows affected MySQL

Tags: mysql, rows, concatenation

Here is my data:

TABLE TAX1

```
tax           | tax_list

abc_132       | empty   
cda_456       | empty    
akc_896       | empty
```

TABLE GENUS

```
taxon_list    | taxon_schema

Bees          | abc_132 cda_456    
Elefants      | akc_896
```

Now I want to fill the empty tax_list from table TAX1 with the taxon_list from table GENUS, where the tax from table TAX1 entry occurs in taxon_schema of TABLE GENUS.

I tried the following solution; the syntax seems to be right but I get "0 rows affected" thus nothing changes!

```
update Tax1 set Tax1.tax_list=(select genus.taxon_list from genus where Tax1.tax_schema like concat('%genus.taxon_schema%'));
```

It should look like this:

```
tax                  |    tax_list

abc_132              | Bees    
cda_456              | Bees
akc_896              | Elefants
```

Comment: What DBMS are you running?

Comment: MySQL   - sorry for the lack of information :(

Comment: `Tax1.tax_schema`, should this be `Tax1.tax`? Or is there another field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a whirl.

```
update Tax1
  set Tax1.tax_list=(
    select genus.taxon_list from genus where genus.taxon_schema like concat('%', Tax1.tax, '%'));
```

Changes:

- Tax1.tax_schema -> Tax1.tax
- concat -> pass multiple params (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- LIKE operands switched

Also, you probably want to add a LIMIT 1 to the select in case it matches > 1 row.